# Oracle developer VM with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, virtualbox

I found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) very good image for VirtualBox with oracle DB and Oracle Linux.
But problem is, that I want to use Oracle 11g, but not 12c as in this image. I can't find link for this iso, but I am sure, that it must be in offcial Oracle site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This one has Oracle 11g database and SQL Developer:
http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/virtualbox/dd/Oracle_Developer_Day.ova
See http://praitheesh.blogspot.nl/2013/10/oracle-developer-day-vm-how-to-use-pre.html for instructions

**EDIT** : Included comment below from @xwinus:

This link works, but requires little workaround. At first, accept the OTN license agreement on some other site, for example here: oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/oedq/downloads/…, then try the above link again. Now it redirects you to the Oracle SSO login page and allows you to download the file.

Comment: Hi link to OVA image is dead.

Comment: @michal.kreuzman This link works, but requires little workaround. At first, accept the OTN license agreement on some other site, for example here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/oedq/downloads/edq-vm-download-2424092.html, then try the above link again. Now it redirects you to the Oracle SSO login page and allows you to download the file.

Comment: Can someone post the size and md5sum of the image form that URL? That would be nice.

Comment: I downloaded and the size is 4345710592, the md5sum: 2754e276bf3469b17402ba253ce4f943 (note, they might update the image and by that change these data)

Answer (score 2):

Jani Hur created a very useful appliance using turnkey Linux. Check his [post](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20130813/oracle-xe-11g).

It **does not** have Oracle installed but took me less than 10 minutes to have it all set. I tried the zend appliance and had a rough time.

Get the [image](http://vm.jani-hur.net/turnkey-oracle-xe-11g.iso) and follow the [instructions](https://github.com/janihur/turnkey-oracle-xe-11g/tree/initial-dev).