# Installing Oracle Xpress Edition on Mac

Tags: oracle, macos

I wanted to install Oracle Xpress Edition on my Mac for practice . Can we install this software  on  Mac  ?

I am unable to find build for  MacOs  on  Oracle Website  .

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.  You'll need to use a VM running linux and install the DB into that.

Here's how to/where to download..

[Oracle developer VM with Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824115/oracle-developer-vm-with-oracle-11g)